# Error "Unexpected token" al intentar usar modulo ECMA2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2015

Estoy probando el uso de los modulos ECMA2015 y algo estare haciendo mal porque no consigo usarlo. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```js
//Archivo libreria.js
export {unaFuncion, otraFuncion};

function unaFuncion() {
  console.log('Escrito desde unaFuncion');
}

function otraFuncion() {
  console.log('Escrito desde otraFuncion');
}

//Archivo main.js
import {unaFuncion, otraFuncion} from 'libreria';
unaFuncion();
otraFuncion();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Probando modulos</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Probando en Chrome version 64.

Comment: lo estoy probando. Espera te respondo.

Comment: no tengo el Node js intalado pero mira este video te ayudará [link video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3oSWwapPKQ)

Comment: Gracias por tu interés pero de momento no he conseguido solucionarlo, sintacticamente el código me parece correcto al igual que los ejemplos del video (y otros que he buscado). @SebastiánLagosYañez

Comment: Lo estas probando en nodejs? o en el navegador?, si es en el navegador NO tiene compatibilidad, revisa esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722621/es6-in-the-browser-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import/41722712

Comment: Vale , por aqui puede estar el problema lo estaba probando en el navegador @vaavDev

Comment: @Serux Ya agregue la respuesta si te funciono te invito a marcar como respuesta correcta de manera que alguien con un problema similar pueda serle esto de utilidad

Comment: @Serux, le das click a la palomita debajo de las flechas de positivo/negativo

Comment: @vaavDev no veia los errores de sintaxis aunque el problema tambien era que estaba probando desde el navegador como dijo SebatiánLagosYañez ya que de manera local no se pueden importar los archivos. Gracias a ambos.

Comment: @Serux excelente, buen aporte a la comunidad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, el script tag para un módulo tiene la sintaxis

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

Si omites `type` el browser asume que es javascript clásico.

Segundo, en tu `main.js` tienes que importar libreria.js con la ruta relativa incluyendo extensión:

```
import { unaFuncion, otraFuncion } from './libreria.js';
```

Usar 'libreria', 'libreria.js' o './libreria' no resuelve a ningún archivo.

Te dejo [un ejemplo funcionando en Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JgWXHZ?p=preview). (probado en Chrome. No todos los navegadores soportan módulos ES6)

Comment: esto funciona solo si tiene el node instalado o solo si coloco `type="module"` funciona?, esa es mi duda.

Comment: No hace falta tener el node instalado , funciona si el navegador soporta modulos ES6 . Una cosa que tambien hay que tener en cuenta para que funcionen es que se debe usar el protocolo http usando por ejemplo un servidor local(http://localhost:8080/index.html ) porque la funcion import no deja cargar modulos desde el sistema (file:///D:/index.html ) daría un error.  @SebastiánLagosYañez

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

La función `import` permite importar (valga la redundancia) las asignaciones (o valores) que estén definidos en el modulo que tratas de importar.

Esta función al leer la documentación que esta en Mozilla

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Podemos leer que apenas se esta implementando de manera nativa en algunos navegadores, y al revisar la documentación de ECMASCRIPT,

(https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)

Conseguimos la lista de los navegadores que admiten el uso de dicha función.

```
Safari 10.1.
Chrome 61.
Firefox 54 – behind the dom.moduleScripts.enabled setting in about:config.
Edge 16.
```

¿Que pasa si deseo utilizarlo?, debo aplicar un transpilador, entre ellos nombra la documentación de Mozilla:

```
Typescript, Babel, Webpack y Parcel
```

Enlace de la respuesta del sitio en ingles:

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722621/es6-in-the-browser-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import/41722712)